# How to open a file in log directory with finder

Tags: php, file, symfony

I try to open a log file in `app/logs/myfile.log` with `Finder()` but I do not really know how to do, the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) is not very explicit..

I try to do this in my controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

class LogController extends Controller
{
    public function indexLogListAction()
    {
        $finder = new Finder();
        $test = $finder->files()->in('myfile.log');
        var_dump($test);exit;
    }
}
```

but it returns this error :

> The "myfile.log" directory does not exist.

My controller is in `src/acme/bundle/controller/mycontroller.php`

Comment: You need to specify the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `in` in `Finder` instance set the directory, which will search.

```
$finder = new Finder();
$finder
  ->in('path/to/log/directory') // Search in directory
  ->files() // Search only files
  ->name('myfile.log'); // File name pattern search
```